# Microsoft Outlook for Bac Tab/Indent

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, tabs, autoindent, indent

In Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.15

I'd like to be able to create a numbered list (starting with number 1) and after pressing enter and tab, the second line should auto indent (and become a). This used to be the setting but I did something and the setting changed. Now there are extra steps to get the bullet or numbered list to increase the indent.

Samples in the pics are as follows:
[Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ5bM.jpg): a numbered list
[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7tub.jpg): how the numbered list looks after I press the tab on line 2 and 3
[Sample 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ9fV.jpg): how the numbered list looks after I highlight line 2 and 3 and then increase indent

I swear I used to be able to just press the tab button and my indents would automatically happen and the bullet or numbered would adjust accordingly.

Comment: I tested this in my Outlook for Mac. Just pressing Enter won't automatically create the multilevel list. However, when pressing tab on line 2 and 3, it should create the list as you want. No need to increase the indent manually. Maybe you can try rebuild the NormalEmail.dotm template to see whether it helps.

Comment: Hi, when I press tab on line 2 and 3 it doesn't create the list (see my sample above sample 2), I have to manually increase the indent. I serached for the NormalEmail.dotm and it comes up as a blank doc.